# install libssl-devel-0.9.8d-alt4.x86_64 in linux

Tags: linux, perl

I am trying to install  **libssl-devel-0.9.8d-alt4.x86_64** in **linux version  5.97**

and openssl version is **OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5**

I am getting below error

**yum install libssl-devel-0.9.8d-alt4.x86_64**

Loaded plugins: security
Cluster                                                                                               | 1.1 kB     00:00
ClusterStorage                                                                                        | 1.1 kB     00:00
Server                                                                                                | 1.1 kB     00:00
VT                                                                                                    | 1.1 kB     00:00
companion                                                                                             |  951 B     00:00
updates                                                                                               |  951 B     00:00
Setting up Install Process

Examining libssl-devel-0.9.8d-alt4.x86_64.rpm: libssl-devel-0.9.8d-alt4.x86_64

Marking libssl-devel-0.9.8d-alt4.x86_64.rpm to be installed

Resolving Dependencies

--> Running transaction check

---> Package libssl-devel.x86_64 0:0.9.8d-alt4 set to be updated

--> Processing Dependency: libssl6 = 0.9.8d-alt4 for package: libssl-devel

--> Processing Dependency: sh for package: libssl-devel

--> Finished Dependency Resolution

libssl-devel-0.9.8d-alt4.x86_64 from /libssl-devel-0.9.8d-alt4.x86_64 has depsolving problems

--> Missing Dependency: libssl6 = 0.9.8d-alt4 is needed by package libssl-devel-0.9.8d-alt4.x86_64 (/libssl-devel-0.9.8d-alt4.x86_64)

libssl-devel-0.9.8d-alt4.x86_64 from /libssl-devel-0.9.8d-alt4.x86_64 has depsolving problems

--> Missing Dependency: sh is needed by package libssl-devel-0.9.8d-alt4.x86_64 (/libssl-devel-0.9.8d-alt4.x86_64)

Error: Missing Dependency: libssl6 = 0.9.8d-alt4 is needed by package libssl-devel-0.9.8d-alt4.x86_64 (/libssl-devel-0.9.8d-alt4.x86_64)

Error: Missing Dependency: sh is needed by package libssl-devel-0.9.8d-alt4.x86_64 (/libssl-devel-0.9.8d-alt4.x86_64)

You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem

You could try running: package-cleanup --problems

```
                    package-cleanup --dupes

                    rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.

**am I insatalling correct version of libssl for OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhe15??**

**if not where can I get correct version?**

**can anyone suggest solution?**

Thanks Inadvance

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: Missing Dependency: libssl6 = 0.9.8d-alt4 is needed by package libssl-devel-0.9.8d-alt4.x86_64 (/libssl-devel-0.9.8d-alt4.x86_64)

Error: Missing Dependency: sh is needed by package libssl-devel-0.9.8d-alt4.x86_64 (/libssl-devel-0.9.8d-alt4.x86_64)
```

Try to install the above missing packages first.

Comment: what Missing Dependency: sh?

Comment: dependency required :cerificateverifier

Comment: Then you need to install that dependency also.

Comment: I guess need to install dependencies, is there any way to get all in one module?

Comment: frustated to install all dependencies

Comment: Use a package manager, which will help to install dependencies automatically. Which distro are you using?

Comment: Linux x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux and perl 5.8.8